# Fill Array of Objects with Dates Between 2 Dates

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have an array of objects like:

```
const dates = [
  {date: "Jul 06 2018", count: 10},
  {date: "Jul 08 2018", count: 1},
  {date: "Jul 10 2018", count: 120},
];
```

I am working with the [eachDay](https://date-fns.org/docs/eachDay) and [format](https://date-fns.org/v1.9.0/docs/format) functions of [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) to generate and "backfill" all dates that exist between the first and last dates for the given array.

```
eachDay(
  dates[0].date,
  dates.slice(-1)[0].date,
)
  .map(d => ({
    x: d.dateCollected,
    y: dates
      .filter(e => d.dateCollected === format(e, 'MMM DD YYYY')),
  }));
```

That codes returns all the dates, but I cannot get the `count` value from the original array into the "backfilled" array.

The expected outcome:

```
const result =  = [
  {x: "Jul 06 2018", y: 10},
  {x: "Jul 07 2018", y: 0},
  {x: "Jul 08 2018", y: 1},
  {x: "Jul 09 2018", y: 0},
  {x: "Jul 10 2018", y: 120},
];
```

Comment: Why do define `x` and `y` properties in your code when the expected outcome should not have those properties? What is the idea?

Comment: Updated - I inadvertently copy/pasted from the first object. The expected outcome would be with `x` and `y` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things by creating a lookup of count by date:

```js
const {eachDay, format} = dateFns;

const dates = [
  {date: "Jul 06 2018", count: 10},
  {date: "Jul 08 2018", count: 1},
  {date: "Jul 10 2018", count: 120}
];

const counts = dates.reduce((memo, {date, count}) => {
  memo[date] = count;
  return memo;
}, {});

const result = eachDay(
  dates[0].date,
  dates.slice(-1)[0].date
)
  .map(d => {
    const x = format(d, "MMM DD YYYY");
    return {x, y: counts[x] || 0};
  })

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`eachDay`](https://date-fns.org/docs/eachDay) the function returns string values, not objects with a `dateCollected` property.

You could produce the desired result it like this:

```js
const {eachDay, format} = dateFns; // Just needed for this snippet to run

const dates = [
  {date: "Jul 06 2018", count: 10},
  {date: "Jul 08 2018", count: 1},
  {date: "Jul 10 2018", count: 120},
];

const result = eachDay(
  dates[0].date,
  dates.slice(-1)[0].date,
).map(x => format(x, "MMM DD YYYY"))
.map(x => ({ x, y: (dates.find(d => d.date === x) || { count: 0 }).count }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```